# dynamically settings elements top and left in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

Can somebody help me by letting me know if we can set the x and y parameters dynamically
while generating reports **using JasperReports instead of predefined values** for the co-ordinates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can.

You can use [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) or [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/api-docs/) for this purpose. With help of these Java API we can dynamically build the report design.